# Showing up late at workplace

Tags: motivation

I recently (about 2 months ago) hired in a software development company as SysAdmin.

The main reason I got hired was to improve my skills in SysAdmin and DevOps stuff, I had my own dedicated server and was selling VMs and hosts to people, but I realize it's time to face bigger problems.

But they haven't given me any servers till now that I can work with or even keep maintenance of them which I understand as they're very sensitive so every work that I've done till now is research and giving advice to my bosses about how we can improve our security, speed, reliability, etc.

It's not like that I don't want to get to work early, I even installed an alarm app on my phone which starts ringing and doesn't have any snooze button and I should take off my bed and take a picture of my bathroom to stop it from ringing, it works for a few days, but recently I take a picture and tell myself why should I bother myself going to job I don't have any work to do and go back to sleep.

It's been two or three weeks that I've got really nothing to do at work and because of that I can't push myself to wake up in the mornings and get to work and Normally I'm late 3 or 4 hours. Nothing has said anything to me till now because of that and I don't get paid based on work hours.

Actually it's my second job aside from freelancing stuff and my own servers. The first one was pretty much worse, I was called "IT Manager" and the most useful thing I had to do was connecting wires to my coworkers PCs which they accidentally disconnects.

One year I was without a job and I woke up every day at 6 AM to get to my university library to get work done on my own servers and experience stuff on it, so I can tell I don't have medical issue.

Should I talk to my boss about getting my some useful jobs or continue researching on my own?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I installed an alarm app on my phone which doesn't stop screaming until I get a photo of my bathroom, but recently I even take a photo and tell myself I don't have anything to do so why not sleep a little more.
I want to force myself but how?

Comment: We can't really handle ethical questions for the most part. If you have a concrete goal though, we might be able to help you with that.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: It's my second job actually and I quit my first job just because of not having useful work to do. I was called "IT Manager" and the most useful thing I did was installing printer driver on my coworkers computers.

Comment: What is your desired outcome of this question? Do you want help to get up early or get interesting tasks at your job or something entirely different? As it stands, your question is off topic.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - For one year I didn't have any job and I wake up in 6 AM to get to library of my university and getting work done on my servers and experiencing anything you could imagine on them, so I think I do care about this kind of job. I go every one or two hours to my job and asking him if he has any job and mostly he just tells me stuff that aren't relevant at all and telling me that right now he is so busy that he can't assign me tasks.

Comment: @DaveG Actually I wonder if that's the case too, but I was on time the first month every day, and If you could please read my other comment I waked up early even when I didn't have job.

Comment: @YElm I want to know how can I approach this kind of workplace and boss to get me interesting tasks and should I get paid less because of getting late or not?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - That's the point, I don't need money from this job, I'm getting paid well from my own servers, As I said in my question I was hoping to get in a workplace which I can face more major problems.

Comment: @AminVakil Well, if you are researching and giving advice on improving performance, speed, reliability, isn't that improving your skills as a system administrator?  Isn't that knowledge extremely valuable?  Can you use that learning as motivation?

Comment: If you dont need the money, then ask for more tasks or look for another job where you can use your skills

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - You understood my situation completely. Very well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you should talk to your boss behind closed doors. Ask him for 30 minutes of his time and make an appointment if he doesn't have time for you right now.

Explain the situation to him

- Apologize for coming so late to work.
- Explain the reason for being so late. Tell him that you lack the motivation to get up early because you have no real task at work.
- Tell him your wish / plan for the future. This depends entirely on you, but it could be:

  - You wish to have some meaningfull task and finally do what the job advert promised you. You're willing to work for another team as long as they have something to do for you.
  - You wish to solve complicated problems, even if they are not entirely in your job description. You're willing to take on any problem and help any team, even if said problem is not strictly part of your job.
  - You wish to quit.

Discuss the current situation together and try to find a solution that satisfies both of you. Listen to the proposals of your boss and offer your own. If he cannot offer a solution, set an ultimatum in 2 weeks.

If your boss can offer you an interesting task but you still feel unable to get out of bed, you should really seek the professional help of a psychologist or neurologist. Lack of motivation and drive might be a symptom of depression and should be treated by medical professionals.

Comment: This is generally good advice, but there's really no reason to go into being late. If they're not complaining, don't make a problem of it. Concentrate instead on the real problem: you have no work to do.

Answer (score 4):

You will not get into major problems if you canot reliably solve minor ones first.

Showing up 3-4 hours late to the job is not reliable.

"**How can you motivate yourself if you do not need the money**" basically this is your mainpoint.
Do your tasks and have something interesting to fill while you cannot do anything
eg; read guides,books, start scripting ( automating annoying tasks ) etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I talk to my boss about getting my some useful jobs

Yes you should, at least suggest you can look at their current configurations to see if anything could be improved and familiarise yourself with the structure.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have several problems at hand here:

1. You are not getting the tasks you expect from you SysAdmin role and that seems to bore you
2. You are not dependend on the salary that job provides you and that deflates your motivation because of 1.
3. You are showing up 3-4 hours late

I would start by asking myself the following questions:

1. Why are you doing this job?

If you do live off your own work, What motivated you to apply for the role in the first place?

2. Do you want to keep the job?

Its fair enough to quit and tell your boss it just doesn't work for you. Otherwise you should get into a conversation with the people who are responsible for the tasks you get and tell them about how your expectations are not met. Tell them what you expected to do in the role and that you are missing something. Make a suggestion how you would improve your situation. Ask for feedback why you do not get the tasks you are expecting. Be open for feedback even if you do not like it - it could very well be that some people noticed that you show up late and judged you for being not "dependable".

Addressing your third problem: Bore-Out is a real thing. Doing this that are not nearly challenging enough can drive you mad and depressed, and its probably the reason you are not getting out of bed. Find something that is worth getting up for. If its not work, prepare yourself the best coffee you can make yourself first thing in the morning or something like this.

Besides that, depending which of your problems you would like to have answered you might be better of asking your question on a different site. Not getting out of bet is not an ethical workplace issue.